# Is there any difference between %eax(,%edx,$4) and (%eax,%edx,$4) in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I just want to know if there is any difference between those ways to compute some value (either numeric value or address).
%eax(,%edx,$4) and  (%eax,%edx,$4)

as I understand they add do %edx * 4 + %eax
Then I am not sure if we would like to use one way over another at certain situations. Thank you

Comment: They should be the same, if your assembler supports both. Personally I have never seen the first form, only the second. Usually you write a constant offset outside of the `()`, the base register should be the first item inside.

Answer (score 0):

Both are invalid.  The scale factor must not have a `$`.

`(%eax,%edx,4)` is valid, and corresponds to Intel syntax `[eax + edx*4]`.

But `%eax(,%edx,4)` is also invalid.  You could have just tried it:

```
$ cat > foo.S
mov %eax,  %eax(,%edx,4)
(control-D)
$ gcc -c foo.S
foo.S: Assembler messages:
foo.S:1: Error: junk `(,%edx,4)' after register
```

Or with clang:

```
foo.S:1:15: error: unexpected token in argument list
mov %eax, %eax(,%edx,4)
              ^
```

Or http://godbolt.org/ has an assembly source mode, or you could use it in an `asm("");` statement in C++.